# Python to MySQL/MariaDB Insert Error

Tags: python-2.7, mariadb

So I am trying to write a python program to automatically keep track of my mutual funds. I just started and found myself stuck at pretty much the beginning.

Following is the code I am using (just a dummy insert block which I shall parametrize later):

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

host        =       "some host"                 #server where mariadb is hosted. Diskstation in my case
user        =       "some uname"                #mariadb user
password    =       "some pwd"                  #mariadb password
schema      =       "portfolio"                 #schema to be used                      

db    = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, password, schema)
curs  = db.cursor()

try:
        curs.execute ("""delete from portfolio.mutual_funds""")
        db.commit()
        curs.execute ("""INSERT INTO mutual_funds (mf_id, mf_name, mf_nav, mf_nav_dt) VALUES (%s, %s, %l, %s)""", (120523,"Axis Fund",14.6357,88888))
        db.commit()
except db.Error as error:
         print("Error: {}".format(error))
         db.rollback()

#display the table contents
    curs.execute("""SELECT * from portfolio.mutual_funds""")
    print curs.fetchall()

curs.close()
db.close()
```

I get these random errors.

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159,
>   in execute
>       query = query % db.literal(args) ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 43

What am I doing wrong? I've spent two days trying go past this impediment and have failed. Somebody please pull me out of this.

BTW I am using MariaDB installed on a Synology Diskstation and running the queries from Python 2.7 installed on a raspberry Pi.

Comment: This is literally the first time, I saw non-string conversions tried for DBAPI. From the [code](https://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/mysqldb-2/ci/default/tree/MySQLdb/cursors.py#l185), the mysqldb module does not support those, either. Try `(%s, %s, %s, %s)`, the string conversion is enforced by the encoder, anyway. The error message looks weird, though.

Comment: You may try : (%s, "%s", %l, %s),(120523,"Axis Fund",14.6357,88888)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `%s, %s, %l, %s` to `%%s, %%s, %%l, %%s`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I had tried the listed options but somehow things didn't work. Finally I was able to tweak the code a bit (split up the query and parameters) and the following code worked for me:

```
        needed_mf_info = (fetched_tuple[0],fetched_tuple[3],fetched_tuple[4],datetime.datetime.strptime(fetched_tuple[7],'%d-%b-%Y'))

        query = "INSERT INTO mutual_funds(mf_id, mf_name, mf_nav, mf_nav_dt) " \
        "VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)"

        #Inserting into the table
        try:                                                    
                curs.execute(query, needed_mf_info)
                db.commit()                 

        except db.Error as error:
            print("Error: {}".format(error))
            db.rollback()
```